# How to run Puppetter (Chromium) visibly in a github codespaces?

Tags: node.js, github, puppeteer, codespaces, github-codespaces

I have a problem when trying to run Puppeteer in visible mode in a GitHub Codespaces.

I guess because GitHub doesn't have a renderer as well as a local machine.

Is there any way to run Puppeteer, connect it to a port to make it visible or other alternative, I hope for your help.

I want it to run in this mode:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
```

I have tested:
-Install a view server, such as Xvfb.
-Configure Puppeteer to use the view server.

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'], env: { DISPLAY: ':99' } });`

-I did not obtain good results

I hope:
Running Puppeteer on a port in a GitHub Codespaces or other alternative.

Comment: Also looking into this without much luck so far